# Querying through different collection in Arango DB and applying filter on path edges

Tags: go, arangodb, aql, arangojs, pyarango

I have graph DB structure as shown in image below.

[image]

As described, I have **3** document collection - **Collection 1**, **Collection 2**, **Collection 3**. I also have **2** Edge collections - **Edge Collection 1** have an attribute *type* which can take two values *T1* or *T2*, **Edge Collection 2**.

I have a list of documents which satisfy certain filter condition on collection 1 - All documents which have ***status** attribute* as **completed**. Let say the list comes as

```
l1 = [c1a, c1b, c1c]
```

Now, starting with each item in list as start, I need to find the collection **c2** traversing along edge in *Edge Coll 1* and that edge must be of type T1 for that item using edge in Edge Coll 1 and similarly collection item **c3** traversing along edge in *Edge Coll 2*.

After getting both, I need to store it as triplet - {coll 2, coll 1, coll 3} for each coll 1 item found in list

I know I can filter for items in **Edge Coll 1** with *type == T1 and _from == coll 1._id*.

Similarly, I can repeat for **Edge Coll 2** and combine the both results in my backend (GoLang).

But, that would be slow and would be better if I am able to do using graph traversals and in single macro (similar to SQL macro). I will be needing only one backend call to DB then.

Comment: This sounds like a simple query, but I'm not sure I understand the model properly.  How are `Edge Coll 1` and `Edge Coll 2` different - is it just the `type` property?  And what constitutes "a triplet" - how do you arrive at or calculate these three values?

Comment: Hi @kerry, thanks for the comment. But, as you pointed out, it is a simple query. I was too much consumed in optimizing and did not realize that the simplest query is also the optimized one. There might exist even more optimized one, but for the time being I am content. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity in my post. I will keep in mind your points in the future :)